# Prove that for a convergent row $(a_{n})_{n\ge1}\in\mathbb{R}$ $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|\le\epsilon+\frac{N}{n}|a|$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that for a row  $(a_{n})_{n\ge1}\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ that when $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n>N$, $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$ that also for all $n>N$ the following holds:

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|\le\epsilon+\frac{N}{n}|a|$$

But when I try to prove this I get that the $\le$ should be $<$, because $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$. My steps:

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}(a_{k}-a) -\frac{N}{n}a\right|$$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|\le\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}(a_{k}-a)\right| +\frac{N}{n}|a|$$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|\le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}|a_{k}-a| +\frac{N}{n}|a|$$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a \right|<\frac{n-N}{n}\epsilon +\frac{N}{n}|a|<\epsilon+\frac{N}{n}|a|$$

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I noticed... I was about to post that my solution requires strictly less than.

Comment: @Gehakmolen But [Nicholas R. Peterson](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/81839/nicholas-r-peterson) in his comment proved the strict inequality and in your question you don't have a strict inequality.

Comment: Well yeah, thats why I am confused. The question in my book states it should be $\le$ but I have that it should be a strict inequality. Am I right, or the book?

Comment: I think your interpretation of the symbol $\sum \limits_{k=N+1}^{n}a_{k}-a$ is not the intended one. Though I agree that your interpretation is correct, the author probably intends $\sum \limits_{k=N+1}^{n}(a_{k}-a)$. But any of the interpretations seems to yield a strict inequality.

Comment: Yes but in that case it would evaulate to $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}(a_{k}-a) \right|<\epsilon$. I have had contact with my teacher and the summation should only be over $a_{k}$ (sloppy notation on his side).